# AWS Glue job run not respecting Timeout and not stopping

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am running AWS Glue jobs using PySpark. They have set Timeout (as visible on the screenshot) of 1440 mins, which is 24 hours. Nevertheless, the job continues working over those 24 hours.

[image: Summary table from AWS tab Glue/ETL/Jobs]

When this particular job had been running for over 5 days I stopped it manually (clicking stop icon in column "Run status" in GUI visible on the screenshot). However, since then (it has been over 2 days) it still hasn't stopped - the "Run status" is `Stopping`, not `Stopped`.

Additionally, after about 4 hours of running, new logs (column "Logs") in CloudWatch regarding this Job Run stopped appearing (in my PySpark script I have `print()` statements which regularly and often log extra data). Also, last *error* log in CloudWatch (column "Error logs") has been written 24 seconds after the date of the newest log in "Logs".

This behaviour continues for multiple jobs.

My questions are:

1. What could be reasons for Job Runs not obeying set Timeout value? How to fix that?
2. Why the newest log is from 4 hours since starting the Job Run, while the logs should appear regularly during 24 hours of the (desired) duration of the Job Run?
3. Why the Job Runs don't stop if I try to stop them manually? How can they be stopped?

Thank you in advance for your advice and hints.

Comment: Have you found the solution for your issue?

Comment: @fear_matrix no, I have not. The problem was reported to AWS Support and they finally issued a refund. However then I stopped working on this project so don't know the real solution